# How do I create an exponential distribution in Ruby with the distribution gem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I need the mean to be 2, with starting at 1 up to 10,000 random numbers.

```
require 'distribution'

mean = 2

# generate a rng with exponential distribution
rng = Distribution::Exponential.rng(mean)
```

Comment: What do you mean how? You just did it? Your code creates a random number generator that generates numbers in an exponential distribution with rate parameter 0.5.

Comment: In case you are not aware, you don't need a gem to generate an exponential random variate: `-mean*Math.log(rand)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'm not much of a statistician, so I'm a little lost in the code here.

Can you tell me, then, is the first parameter to `rng` (it is named `l`) supposed to stand for "limit"?

If so, I don't really know, I'm getting the same sort of results that you must be getting, but again, I'm not a statistician or even a mathematician, I just like to code, so I am probably not of too much help.

**EDIT:** So, again, I dont really know what is going on or is supposed to be going on here. Here is what gives me a relatively close mean of 2 (I got this just by messing around with the `l` value):

```
require 'distribution'
rng=Distribution::Exponential.rng(0.5)
sum=0
1000.times { sum += rng.call }
sum /= 1000
puts sum
```

Seems to give a value generally between 1.9 and 2.1. Hope this helps :)

**PRINT EACH VALUE:**

```
require 'distribution'
rng = Distribution::Exponential.rng(0.5)
values = [] # we'll store each value in an array

# calculate the results
how_many = 1000 # let's store 1000 in a variable since we'll reuse the value
how_many.times { values << rng.call } # rng is now a Proc, so we use call to get our value

# print out the results
values.each_with_index { |v,i| puts "#{i+1}: #{v}" } # print each value one by one
puts
puts "Total sum: #{values.inject(&:+)}"
puts "Mean: #{values.inject(&:+)/how_many}"
```

Again, not sure if this is exactly "right" or what you're looking for, but it definitely seems to approach 2. Try a bigger number than 1000, like 100000.

Comment: Thanks this helps. How would I print all the 1000 values?

Comment: Why did you input 0.5?

Comment: Well, as I said, I am not much of a math guy -- I understand mathematical concepts with relative ease but simply don't pursue it. Anyway, I'm not sure why 0.5 seems to give you the mean of 2. What I did was started trying different values. I noticed through the code that the value going in there was generally between 0 and 1.

Then I just started trying 0.1, 0.2, etc. Ran on 0.5 and noticed it was seemingly producing the result you desired.

See my edit to print each value. :)

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot... Now I just gotta figure out how to plot it using nyaplot gem.

Comment: I'd help you with that if I knew anything about it. Best of luck, man.